# Varrer vários checkbox em um groupbox C#

Tags: c#

Bom dia!!

Tenho varios checkboxes dentro do mesmo form em GroupBoxes separados por porgunta. Gostaria de varrer todos esse checkboxes que estao dentro dos GroupBoxes onde se checked receber S se nao receber N e o resultado, fique em uma String concatenada.

Exemplo:

3 sim, 4 nao: String resultado = "SSSNNNN".

Já tentei de várias formas, uma dela foi:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String meat = "";
    foreach (Control gb in this.Controls)
    {
        if (gb is GroupBox)
        {
            foreach (Control chk in gb.Controls)
            {
                if (chk is CheckBox)
                {
                    CheckBox c = chk as CheckBox;
                    if (c.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
                    {
                        meat += "S";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        meat += "N";
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(meat);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}**
```

Mas o resultado sai letra por letra e nao todas juntas.

Answer (score 0):

Você está exibindo a mensagem dentro do loop. Basta exibi-la fora:

```
String meat = "";
foreach (Control gb in this.Controls)
{
    if (gb is GroupBox)
    {
        foreach (Control chk in gb.Controls)
        {
            if (chk is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox c = chk as CheckBox;
                meat += c.Checked ? "S" : "N";
            }
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show(meat);
```